# Problems creating .NET Core 1.1 Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I am having issues creating a .NET Core 1.1 Web Application. I've found postings outlining similar issues other people have had, but they either have a slightly different issue, or have an accepted answer that didn't work for me, or that doesn't have enough details for me to actually implement. I'm going to post step-by-step what I have installed and what I'm doing to create the application, and hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3 installed:

[image: About Microsoft Visual Studio]

I've installed the .NET Core 1.1 SDK:

[image: .NET Core 1.1 SDK]

I’ve also installed the tools (Preview 2) for .NET Core 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015:

[image: Tools (Preview 2) for .NET Core 1.1]

I opened Visual Studio 2015 and created a new Web API project targeting .NET Core:

[image: New Project]

I modified the solution's global.json to target .NET Core 1.1:

[image: global.json]

I modified the project.json to target .NET Core 1.1:

[image: project.json]

I ran Update-Package in the package manager console:

[image: Update-Package]

I ran "dotnet restore" in the package manager console:

[image: dotnet restore]

And here I can see things going wrong...I'm getting a bunch of "Unable to resolve" errors...which, of course, means my subsequent "dotnet build" action fails:

[image: dotnet build]

So...why is it failing to find the dependencies. And/or, what exactly do I do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
Check if you have installed SDK for both x86 and x64 - in other words check both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`.

From my experience, you need them both - and don't ask me why
    because I don't know.

**2.**
Check your configuration of NuGet manager - I'm using two sources and everything works fine for me (probably first one is enough):

- NuGet.org: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
- AspNetCore: https://dotnet.myget.org/f/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json

**3.**
Clean up your `Temp` folder and `NuGet cache` folders:

- `c:\Users\ ?? \.nuget\packages\`
- `c:\Users\ ?? \AppData\Local\NuGet\`

**4.**
You can edit `project.json` file manually and then run `Restore packages` (right click on `References`).

Here is my working configuration (you can just copy-paste it into your `project.json`):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Quick update: I had previously only installed the SDK for x64. Installing it for x86 as well does not fix the issue.

Comment: do all steps ;) I had similar problem a few days ago and clearing the NuGet cache was the solution in my case.

Comment: In the meantime I have added my working configuration as an example, please refer it.

Comment: I was missing those entries in my NuGet manager, after adding those I am down to one error left that doesn't have to do with resolving dependencies, which is a call to  IApplicationBuilder.UserBrowserLink(). I don't actually use this and removing it allows my app to build. Thanks for the help!